# How to put json array in json object

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is code which I'm using:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "GetCalender_Events";
    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrlArray(yourJsonStringUrl);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
            ldatosAgenda.add(new DatosAgenda(c.getString("Event_Name"), c.getString("Event_Name"),
                    sdf5.format(sdf1.parse(c.getString("Column1"))), sdf6.format(sdf1.parse(c.getString("Column1"))),
                    c.getString("Description")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How to put my JSON Array into JSON object? Can anyone please help me, this is my first try with JSON Array.

My array looks like this:

```
{
  "ContactList": [
    {
      "Column1": "22-05-2017",
      "Event_Name": "Garba Compition",
      "Description": "School organized garba compition"
    },
    {
      "Column1": "24-05-2017",
      "Event_Name": "Mahendi Compition",
      "Description": "Mahendi compition"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you read the JavaDoc? What did you not understand about how to add array into object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#.** Seems you are getting `JSONObject` as response. So you have to parse `JSONObject` first from sever response:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrlObject(yourJsonStringUrl);
```

**#.** Then parse `ContactList` and its item as below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("ContactList");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try 
        {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ldatosAgenda.add(new DatosAgenda(c.getString("Event_Name"),c.getString("Event_Name"), sdf5.format(sdf1.parse(c.getString("Column1"))), sdf6.format(sdf1.parse(c.getString("Column1"))),c.getString("Description")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

try{
    jsonObject.put(jsonarray);
} catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You get the values

```
JSONArray songobj = json.getJSONArray("ContactList");
Log.d(TAG, "List Length" + songobj.length());
for (int i = 0; i < songobj.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject song = songobj.getJSONObject(i);
     String column=song.getString("Column1");
     String name=song.getString("Event_Name");
     String desc=song.getString("Description");
     ldatosAgenda.add(new DatosAgenda(column,name,desc));
  }
}
```